# How to disable embedded database Spring-boot spring-data-jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I can't Read/Write on my Postgresql database (9.4) set up locally. My app always use an embedded database. When I execute some select queries on my database, there is no data inserted. Could you check my files please?

I'm using Spring-boot with Spring-Data-JPA.

File : **application.properties**

```
##DATABASE PROPERTIES
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDataBase
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

File : **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MyApp</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

File : **Application.java**

```
package fr.mydomain.myApp.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "fr.mydomain.myApp.*" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "fr.mydomain.myApp.dao")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "fr.mydomain.myApp.model")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

File : **Customer.java**

```
package fr.mydomain.myApp.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    /** ID of the customer */
    private long customerID;

    @Column
    /** Lastname of the customer */
    private String lastname;

    @Column
    /** Firstname of the customer */
    private String firstname;

    protected Customer() {

    }

    public Customer(String lastname, String firstname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public long getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(long customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Customer[CustomerID= %d, Lastname= '%s', Firstname= '%s'", customerID, lastname,
                firstname);
    }
}
```

File : **CustomerRepository.java**

```
package fr.mydomain.myApp.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import fr.ineatconseil.picomBO.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findCustomerDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);

}
```

File : **BeaconController.java**

```
package fr.mydomain.myApp.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import fr.mydomain.myApp.dao.CustomerRepository;
import fr.mydomain.myApp.model.Customer;

@Controller
public class BeaconController {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Beacon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {

        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Johnny", "Joe"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Bobby", "Bob"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Jean", "Bonbeurre"));
        customerRepository.save(new Customer("Anna-Lyse", "Durine"));

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : customerRepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(2L);
        System.out.println("Customer found with findOne(2L):");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println(customer);
        System.out.println();

        // fetch all customers by lastname or firstname
        System.out.println("Customers found with findCustomerDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer2 : customerRepository.findCustomerDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname("Jack", "Bob")) {
            System.out.println(customer2);
        }
        System.out.println();

        return "beacon";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see a dependency on an embedded database (H2, HSQLDB, etc) in your pom. How have you identified that your app is using one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution this weekend.

I had some tables "Customer" and "Product" with capital letters in my Database with data but and my App created me the tables "customer" and "product". So, it didn't extract my data

:/